# Calling WSDL with different namespaces with Ksoap2 in Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, wsdl, ksoap2

I'm calling a WSDL from Android, with Ksoap2 library. I've done it already, without problems, but this WSDL in particular has a lot of different namespaces and this causes big issues. All i've found is

http://ksoap.objectweb.org/project/mailingLists/ksoap/msg00454.html

and

[How to parse a complex SOAP response in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162598/how-to-parse-a-complex-soap-response-in-android)

Where they said that you can't fix it out of the box so you have to create a QName class and change SoapObject/PropertyInfo to support it. But i have -no- idea how to do this by hand.

Is there someone out there that has done something like it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the namespace for every property you add to the request, so there should not be a problem really. Also you should check out 
http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/ 
for an improved ksoap project that is actively maintained and used on Android.