# How to parse my soap response in android

Tags: android, parsing

I am getting response like that,

```
AuthenticateResponse
{
  AuthenticateResult=anyType{Photo=anyType{}; 
  Result=false; 
};
```

How can I parse it.I want only Result `string` like true or false.

Please help me..

Thank you

Comment: ducli's  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162598/how-to-parse-a-complex-soap-response-in-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409982/how-to-parse-soap-response-in-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767389/how-to-send-soap-request-and-parse-soap-response-in-xml-format-in-android

Comment: yes..i will do it..can u plz tell me the answer..how can I parse..

Comment: http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/167-using-ksoap2-for-android-soap-web-service

Answer (score 0):

This is a JSON response, try to use the [JSON api](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) to parse its content and retrieve the value.

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value AuthenticateResponse of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
 D/dalvikvm(513): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 757 objects / 56160 bytes in 44ms

Comment: that's true, at first glance it looked like a JSON...not sure anymore. I don't recognize this type of response.

Comment: SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
      Log.e("", "u urlenvelop-enevlop-result---"+result.toString() );
      final String ResultObject = result.getProperty(0)
        .toString();
       Log.v("", "we service result1111111 = "+
       ResultObject.toString());
      SoapObject sopObj;
      sopObj = result;
      String AnalystID = ResultObject.substring(
        ResultObject.lastIndexOf("Result"));
      Log.e("RBloginResponseAnalystID value", "schema"
      + AnalystID.toString());

Comment: see I am doing this but still not getting how to get the result string